# gradient of a transformation that uses an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have Y=QX, where Y and X are vectors of dimension n and belong to $R^{n}$, and Q is an orthogonal matrix. Then, why do we have $\nabla_{Y}f=Q\nabla_{X}f$? I know that orthogonal matrices have this property: $Q^{-1}=Q^{T}$. I think that it should be $\nabla_{Y}f=Q^{T}\nabla_{X}f$

Answer (score 1):

Outside standard vector calculus identities one can still derive from first principles. Applying the chain rule we have in this case the following linear map, $d_Xf(Y(X))=d_Yf\circ d_XY=d_Yf\cdot Q$. It takes an argument $H,$ which we write succinctly as $d_Xf(H)=[d_Xf(Y(X))](H)$. Given an inner product we can introduce the gradient vector, e.g., $\langle\nabla_X f,H\rangle=d_Xf(H)$. Let us rewrite our chain rule using 2 gradient vectors: $\langle\nabla_X f,H\rangle=\langle\nabla_Y f,QH\rangle$, or in case of 
Euclidean inner product, $(\nabla_X f)^TH=(\nabla_Y f)^TQH$. Result follows using $Q^{-1}=Q^T.$ Could you show your working, why did you think differently?